# SparkR - extracting dataframe's array<int> for an R function

Tags: arrays, r, apache-spark-sql, sparkr

I have 1000s of sensors, I need to partition the data (i.e. per sensor per day) then submit each list of data points to an R algorithm).   Using Spark, simplified sample looks like:

```
//Spark
val rddData = List(
 ("1:3", List(1,1,456,1,1,2,480,0,1,3,425,0)), 
 ("1:4", List(1,4,437,1,1,5,490,0)),
 ("1:6", List(1,6,500,0,1,7,515,1,1,8,517,0,1,9,522,0,1,10,525,0)),
 ("1:11", List(1,11,610,1))
)

case class DataPoint(
  key:  String,
  value:    List[Int])  // 4 value pattern, sensorID:seq#, seq#, value, state
```

I convert to a parquet file, save it.
Load the parquet in SparkR, no problem, the schema says:

```
#SparkR
df <- read.df(sqlContext, filespec, "parquet")
schema(df)
StructType
|-name = "key", type = "StringType", nullable = TRUE
|-name = "value", type = "ArrayType(IntegerType,true)", nullable = TRUE
```

So in SparkR, I have a dataframe where each record has all of the  data I want (df$value).   I want to extract that array into something R can consume then mutate my original dataframe(df) with a new column holding the resultant array.  Logically something like results = function(df$value).   Then I need to get results (for all rows) back into a SparkR dataframe for output.

How to I extract an array from the SparkR dataframe then mutate with the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let spark data frame be, `df` and R data frame be `df_r`
 To convert sparkR df to R df, use code

`df_r <- collect(df)`

with R data frame `df_r`, you can do all computations you want to do in R.
let say you have the result in column `df_r$result`

```
Then for converting back to SparkR data frame use code,
#this is a new SparkR data frame, df_1
df_1 <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, df_r) 

For adding the result back to SparkR data frame `df` use code
#this adds the df_1$result to a new column df$result 
#note that number of rows should be same in df and `df_1`, if not use `join` operation
df$result <- df_1$result
```

Hope this solves your problem

Comment: Thanks, this is hugely helpful.    This led me to more documentation:  https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/api/R/index.html   (which I didn't see before)     However, when I tried the convert(df), I got an error,  Error: could not find function "convert",     df_r <- SparkR:::convert(df) didn't work either.   Do I need a different library for this function?

Comment: sorry its not `convert` its `collect`

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. The way I got around it was by adding a row index into the spark DataFrame and then using `explode` inside a select statement. Make sure to select the index and then the row you want in your select statement. That will get you a "long" dataframe. If each of the nested lists in the DataFrame column has the same amount of information in it (for example if you are exploding a list-column of x,y coordinates), you would expect each row index in the long DataFrame to occur twice.

After doing the above, I typically do a `groupBy(index)` on the exploded DataFrame, filter where the `n()` of each index is *not* equal to the expected number of items in the list and proceed with additional groupBy, merge, join, filter, etc. operations on the Spark DataFrame.

There are some excellent guides on the Urban Institute's GitHub page. Good luck. -nate